# Replace "/?" from string

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to replace `"/?"` by `"?"` in the following URL with R :

```
http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/fr/express/offerings/systemx_intel/?cmp=333AD&c
```

So it will become :

```
http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/fr/express/offerings/systemx_intel?cmp=333AD&c
```

I have tried different functions to replace it (`str_replace_all`, ...) but I have always the same issue, it cannot find the string `"/?"` because it is two special characters.

Comment: can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: There are no special characters. Show your code.

Comment: a question mark is a special character, the forward slash is not.  you probably need to escape the specials with a backslash...  I'd use the `sub()` function

Comment: @SamMason `?` is not a special character in a string. It is, in a regex, but not a string.

Comment: Sorry @Jerry, I should have been more explicit—I presumed the OP knew that as they mentioned "specials".

Comment: @SamMason  It's `R`, so you need to doubly-escape the `?`

Comment: Thanks all, sorry, code was missing, but here was it :                      else if (str_detect(DFA_CMO[i,4], "/?")) {
  DFA_CMO[i,4] = sub("/?" ,"?", DFA_CMO[i,4])
  } I knew I had to do somthing special with this, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how to use the regex replacement function `sub` in this case:

```
x <- 'http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/fr/express/offerings/systemx_intel/?cmp=333AD&c'
sub('/\\?','?',x)
```

Comment: @user2506015, if this resolved it, make sure to hit the check mark next to the answer

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `sub` or `gsub` with the `fixed=TRUE` parameter set. This takes the string representing the pattern you are searching for *as it is* and ignores any special characters.

```
string <- "http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/fr/express/offerings/systemx_intel/?cmp=333AD&c"
sub("/?","?",string,fixed=TRUE)
[1] "http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/fr/express/offerings/systemx_intel?cmp=333AD&c"
```

This may be of help in similar situations.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sub` replaces the first occurrence of a pattern, `gsub` replaces all occurrences.

```
gsub('/\\?','?', x)
```